# Footer section add more than usual heigh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am adding footer section to a simple web page since page has only few items on the page show white space at the bottom of the footer if i keep footer height at 150px. When i keep `height:100%` to take the rest of the space at bottom of the page, Rather it adds 3 - 4 times more to the footer section which show vertical scrollbar.

Is their a way i can only add that much height to footer section so that scrollbar wont be added. even using jQuery.

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/57fBK/10/

In the above mention fiddle example your will notice footer height than usual. To me it seems it by default always take height of HTML elements defined above the footer section.

```
.fullWidth {
   width: 100%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   max-width: initial;
    background-color:red;
    height:100%;
}
.footer
{
    margin-top:50px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Did you check out sticky footer?? I think you looking like that one.

Comment: I don't get what the question is, and also, I don't see anything wrong with the positioning of the page in the fiddle you provided!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that giving `height:100%` to `.fullWidth` makes it 100% of the *viewport* height...which means, if there's any content above it that pushes it down, `.fullWidth` is going to extend that much below the bottom of the viewport, creating a scrollbar. If you're only looking to visually have the footer appear to fill the remaining space (between the content and the bottom of the viewport), here's a way I've used once to fake it.

Simply make the entire `body` the same background colour as the footer, and place the rest of the content in a wrapper with the main background colour. For example, your HTML might become:

```
<div class="main">
    (Content from before goes in here.)
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

And some altered/added CSS (it should be noted that `.fullWidth` is rendered completely unnecessary by this approach, so you can remove it from your HTML/CSS):

```
body{
    background-color:red; /* Footer background colour */
}
.main{
    background-color:#FFF; /* Main background colour */
}
.footer {
    background-color:red;
    margin-top:50px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57fBK/13/) demonstrating how this looks. Now, if there's extra space below the footer, it won't be perceivable unless you start inspecting elements. If this isn't what you wanted, you may want to look into sticky footers, as others have suggested.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks i think this is the only alternative to it unless to do it with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 .fullWidth {
   width: 100%;
   margin:0 auto;
   max-width: initial;
   background-color:red;
   height:100%;
 }
```

also you need to set height for footer:

```
 .footer
  {
    margin-top:50px;
    text-align:center;
    height: 50px;
  }
```

Comment: I don't see any difference... but at the same time, I am not sure what the question is asking either

Comment: I understand that.. but the result is no different